# WIX Installer: Cannot set more than one appSettings node

Tags: xml, xpath, wix, installation

I have the following in a wix installer:

```
<util:XmlFile Id="leID4" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]app.config" Sequence="5"
                      Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='JobProcessorTimerInterval'[\]]/@value" Value="60000" Permanent="yes" />

<util:XmlFile Id="leID5" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]app.config" Sequence="6"
                      Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='FromEmail'[\]]/@value" Value="[FROMEMAIL]" Permanent="yes" />
```

This is my app.config file:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="FromEmail" value="test@hotmail.com" />
    <add key="JobProcessorTimerInterval" value="60000"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I run the installer I get this message:

> [image]

I have tried multiple paths but I can't seem to get this working. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just being curious: What are these funny `[\]` and `\[]` character sequences intermingled in the XPath expressions?

Comment: Marcus - "[\]" escape character in XPATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the one below? The WIX documentation states that:

> "setValue - Sets a value in the element specified in the ElementPath. If
>   Name is specified, and attribute with that name is set to the value
>   specified in Value. If Name is not specified, the text value of the
>   element is set. Value is a required attribute if setValue is the
>   action specified."

```
    <util:XmlFile Id="leID4" 
                        File="[#filename]" 
                        Sequence="5"
                        Action="setValue" 
                        ElementPath="//appSettings/add[\[]@key='JobProcessorTimerInterval'[\]]" 
                        Name="value" 
                        Value="60000" 
                        Permanent="yes" 
                        SelectionLanguage="XPath" />

    <util:XmlFile Id="leID5"
                        File="[#filename]" Sequence="6"
                        Action="setValue" 
                        ElementPath="//appSettings/add[\[]@key='FromEmail'[\]]" 
                        Name="value" 
                        Value="[FROMEMAIL]" 
                        Permanent="yes" 
                        SelectionLanguage="XPath" />

<File Id="filename" Name="xmlfiletest" Source="..\\xmlfile1.xml">
          </File>
```

filename is the ID attribute of the FILE element in your WIX for the app.config file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and I get the same error on the FromEmail attribute.

Comment: Thanks again, added it and failed with the same message

Comment: Do you have any specific XML namespace mentioned within the CONFIG file? Looks like there is a bug in XMLUTIL about lack of namespace handling.

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/XmlFile-Failed-to-find-node-td7592271.html

Comment: Yes I saw a few threads on that topic, but there are no namespaces in my config file

Comment: I just tested this on my machine and it worked, the only change I did was change the XmlFile "File" attribute, I changed the attribute to the name of the ID attribute of the WIX FILE element for the app.config file.

Comment: Sorry, just got a chance to test it now. Yes it did, thanks for the help!